# C# Cannot access DataTables column via its columnname

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, mvvm, datatable

I have a DataTable which I save into a CSV file.

If I now read that CSV file and fill the value of it into a new DataTable the first column has a questionmark before it. Like '?Strasse'.
I guess there is a encoding issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

Code that generates CSV:

```
private static void SaveProgressToCSV(List<DataTable> dts)
        {
            int count = 0;
            _pathToCSVs = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataTable dt in dts)
            {
                count++;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                                  Select(column => column.ColumnName);
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field =>
                      string.Concat("\"", field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\""));
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
                }

                File.WriteAllText(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + @"\save"+ count + ".csv", sb.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);

                _pathToCSVs.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + @"\save" + count + ".csv");
            }
        }
```

Code that reads CSV:

```
private static void ReadCSVIntoDataTable()
        {
            DataTable = new List<System.Data.DataTable>();
            foreach (String pathToSave in _pathToSave)
            {
                DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

                string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToSave);
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(pathToSave);

                string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";

                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
                          @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
                          ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=Yes;CharacterSet=65001;\""))
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }

                DataTable.Add(dt);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the two string values are exactly equal.  What if you do `Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[0].ColumnName == "Strasse");`  I just wonder because the German word for road can also be "Straße"

Comment: @juharr it gives me `false` back. 
Thanks for the advice, but I am german. In the tooltipp for `ColumnName` is `Strasse` . I called road on purpose `Strasse` so I don't have issues later with that word.

Comment: But when I write `Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[0].ColumnName)` it gives me `?Strasse` back.

Am I doing something wrong in my reading CSV method? Can you please help me here? Thanks!

Comment: I'd usually use a CSV parser library vs the Ole DB solution you have, but I can only guess that it's the reason for the "?" at the beginning of the column name, but I'm not sure why.  You might want to update your question to ask why that's happening.

Comment: @juharr I did, thank you.

Comment: I think this is related to the Extended Properties in your connection string. Specifically Encoding/CharacterSet (you write the file using UTF8).  Here is an article with a similar issue (check the LAST post). https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/95a12042-65c9-481b-896b-256c22a12188/encoding-problem-with-oledbconnection?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: How your Q is related to WPF?

Comment: a friendly advice!!! ditch Oledb and go for your own reading of CSV. Believe me u will only have headaches after headaches.... or there are some commercial libraries available. But i dont have experience with them

Comment: @FoggyFinder the question itself is not related to WPF, my project is, so I added it. I probably should'nt have had, sorry bout that.

Comment: okay, got it. If you have some trouble with your WPF project - feel free come to the [WPF chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @juharr mentioned in the comments, I tried a CSV parser library. 
The one I choose was the `GenericParser`.

Here the code including the `GenericParser` that fixed my encoding issue:

```
private static void ReadCSVIntoDataTable()
        {
            foreach (String pathToSave in _pathToSave)
            {
                var adapter = new GenericParsing.GenericParserAdapter(pathToSave, Encoding.UTF8);
                adapter.FirstRowHasHeader = true;

                DataTable dt = adapter.GetDataTable();

                DataTableToExpose.Add(dt);
            }
        }
```

Thanks for the help @everyone.